# jQuery and Ajax on Form submit - parse POST data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax jQuery code that on document.ready function downloads a file from ajaxFileDownload.php.

However, I would like it to instead of `document.ready` function use on submit of a form called reports. So when i click submit on my form name report, then it runs this, I would also like to parse the form field post variable called `user_id` to the php file.

Any ideas how this can be done?

I added: `$('#reports').on('submit', function(e) {`

How can I add the user_id post variable?

```
$(function () {
    $('#reports').on('submit', function(e) {
        var $preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file-modal");
        $preparingFileModal.dialog({
            modal: true
        });
        $.fileDownload('ajaxFileDownloader.php?' + Math.random(), {
            successCallback: function (url) {
                $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
            },
            failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
                $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
                $("#error-modal").dialog({
                    modal: true
                });
            }
        });
        return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
    });
});
```

Comment: Where from are you planning to get `user_id`? Also did you read about `data` withing [`jQuery.Ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Comment: @kingkero i'm planning to get the user_id from the same reports form, there is a hidden field with value for user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these two lines inside the `$.fileDownload` block:

```
httpMethod: 'POST',
data: $(this).serialize()
```

like so:

```
$.fileDownload('ajaxFileDownloader.php?' + Math.random(), {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    successCallback: function (url) {
        $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
    },
    failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
        $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
        $("#error-modal").dialog({
            modal: true
        });
    }
});
```

That should send all form data to the PHP script.

If you want to send just the one field, you could use `$('#user_id')` in place of `$(this)` assuming the field in question has `id="user_id"`.